# WPF TextBox accepts only one number

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, textbox

Thanks for reading my thread. I have this problem in VS2012 WPF I have no idea why.

Basically there is a TextBox whose xaml is like following:

```
<TextBox Width="75" Text="{Binding Path=ProcessStart, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

When input is characters (English letters: A, a, B, b, C, c, ... Z, z), it works fins.
However, when input is numbers, this TextBox only accept one digit.

For example:

```
your input from keyboard:           display on this TextBox:
0                                   0
1                                   1
2                                   2
3                                   2
9                                   2
4                                   2
11                                  2
4534                                2
32132435234                         2
1.1                                 2
1.2                                 2
```

I am wondering any has any idea why this is happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can we see the code of what it is bound to (ProcessStart)?

Comment: I believe that something else is changing the ProcessStart value. Or maybe the get/set method is not correct on the ProcessStart property.

Comment: @Vinicius: You are right. I guess my logic in set method is wrong. If you can post your answer (even copy paste), I will accept your answer.

Comment: @EricScherrer: the get methods has something wrong in its logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that something else is changing the ProcessStart value. Or maybe the get/set method is not correct on the ProcessStart property.